# How do i get full-width and half-width to take the same amount of space?

Tags: c++, c

EDIT:  Seems my premise was mistaken. The characters appear to be mixed, but they aren't actually mixed. The next question becomes, "How do I actually reliably turn half-width to full-width? wcswidth exists, so I figure there is a similar routine out there that actually converts.

I've had this burning issue for years: how could one make, say, a game mixing half-width and full-width where a full-width character could take up the same amount of space as a half-width character. I've recently seen an example while googling the problem again in a game called incavead, but it's a bit large of a haystack for the needle that I'm looking for. I figured maybe asking a place like stackoverflow would help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf-8");
        printf("黒猫\n1234\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Simple enough: The problem is, I need the characters 黒 and 猫 to not go past 2 (horizontally). At first, I figured this came down to terminal emulators, but depending on where I SSH or Telnet to, i get different results. With the incavead example, I was able to see ～(full-width) and ~(half-width) take the same amount of space (the developer had used them to represent different things in his program) with the same terminal emulator (mintty) that displayed odd widths using other programs (leading me to believe this is something to be solved in the code, not the terminal emulator). The question is, what is the proper methodology to get characters to display using the same amount of horizontal real-estate?

Comment: Well, you can always download the source code to the terminal emulator itself, and make it do what you want to do. Other than that, there does not seem to be any other options.

Comment: The incavead [screenshots](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Incavead)  show the opposite. They show full-width forms in the map, such as `＠` instead of `@`.

Comment: Have you tried using monospaced fonts?

Comment: It's definitely inconsistent between things i'm connected to no the emulator i'm using. Fonts in particular do not matter, either. There does seem to be some degree of half-width to full-width conversion: when looking through the data files i can't find that one character, but it still looks visibly different from the others. In particular, the first screenshot there is a yellow tilde in addition to the blue, and they are different in more than just color.

Comment: Not a solution, but I think the yellow tilde is a tilde ~ but the blue character is a Japanese wave dash 〜.

Comment: Eagle eye. I was indeed mistaking them.[wikipedia actually addresses this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Unicode_and_Shift_JIS_encoding_of_wave_dash) I wasn't even aware there were separate characters, 'cause i've been on windows for so long and always saw the tilde being used. Even now, when i go to different websites through google to make them full width, they turn ~ into ～. The Blue is apparently an incorrect wavedash, and because of the font i didn't recognize it.

Updating question to be more to the point, 'cause anyone who'd find this would then be looking for the next answer.

Comment: @user108496 is the game written by you? Then just stop using half-width characters. Instead of `"黒猫\n1234\n"` use `"黒猫\n１２３４\n"`. This works unless you need characters outside the full-width block, in which case you'll need to fix the terminal. See also [this](https://superuser.com/a/1302606/241386) which relates to square characters in rogue games

Comment: I want to be able to design my own game, but the game i'm referencing above is not my own. I ultimately want to be able to take user input, as well. Since there doesn't seem to be an easy solution so far, I'm leaning towards using wcswidth() and making tables as needed as bug reports come in. The example you provide does indeed help, but the way unicode is and can always be expanded, it's naturally going to result in need of constant maintenance of the function.